# Hypothesis test with given variation

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am trying to solve the following problem.
But I don't know what is the appropriate formulas I have to use.

Could you help me please ?

A new machine is tested in a factory. It is said that the average weight of a generated product is at least 60kg and variation 3.2kg.
The director of the factory worries that if the average weight is less than 60kg
the factory will have problem. A sample of 45 products have a average 58.1kg
a. In significance value 0.05, is the average weight less than 60kg ?
b. If the variation is 4.2 kg what is the answer in a?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume that the weight of a product is normally distributed.

By hypothesis, $X$=weight of a product has mean $60$ and standard deviation $3.2$. $Y$=the average weight of $45$ products has mean $60$ and standard deviation $\frac{3.2}{\sqrt{45}}=0.477$

To get the critical value, we calculate $60-0.477\times 1.64=59.22$
The observed value is smaller, so we can concolude at the $5$%-level
that the average weight is less than $60$.

If the standard derivation is $4.2$, we get a critical value $58.97$,
so the conclusion is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. saying X is the null hypothesis and Y is the alternate ?
Also, 1.64 is the Z value for 5% significance level ?

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did.